# How to structure .csv file to allow D3.js to associate a line with a specified color?

Tags: d3.js

I don't have a MWE for this, as it mostly deals with the preprocessing of data prior to writing D3 code.

I have a `.csv` file which is essentially structured as follows:

```
category,value,date
cat1,200000,2016-08-07
cat2,500000,2016-08-07
cat3,600000,2016-08-07
cat1,200000,2016-09-07
cat2,500000,2016-09-07
cat3,600000,2016-09-07
```

and so forth. The task is to draw a line graph for each one of `cat1`, `cat2`, and `cat3` with the x-axis being the date and the y-axis being the value. From every example I've found, the solution appears to be that there must be one date per row:

```
date,cat1,cat2,cat3
2016-08-07,200000,500000,600000
2016-09-07,200000,500000,600000
```

which makes sense. However, let's suppose that `cat1`, `cat2`, and `cat3` have required colors that must be associated with them. For example, suppose that the line for `cat1` must have color `#4472C4`, the line for `cat2` must have color `#ED7D31`, and the line for `cat3` must have color `#FFC000`.

What is the best way to structure the data above to not only easily plot the lines, but to associate each line with a specified color?

If a MWE is preferred, please let me know, and I will delete this question until I have a sufficient MWE prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your custom color scale this way:

```js
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
  .range(["#4472C4", "#ED7D31" , "#FFC000"]);
  
console.log("color('cat1') ==>", color('cat1'));
console.log("color('cat2') ==>", color('cat2'));
console.log("color('cat3') ==>", color('cat3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see it returns the appropriate color for the category name that you pass.

Check the primitive demo how it works in action:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `category,value,date
cat1,200000,2016-08-07
cat2,500000,2016-08-07
cat3,600000,2016-08-07
cat1,400000,2016-09-07
cat2,600000,2016-09-07
cat3,200000,2016-09-07`;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
  .range(["#4472C4", "#ED7D31" , "#FFC000"]);

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
});

var dataByCategory = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.category; })
  .entries(data);
  
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
    
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(dataByCategory)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", function(d){
  console.log(color(d.key))
    return color(d.key);
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return valueline(d.values);
  });
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to class each line by category, then use css to add colour, something like this:

`d3.selectAll("path").data(csv)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d){return d.category}`

Alternatively, you could also add a colour scale which can be seen [here.](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b5935342c6d21928111928401e2c8608)